# CPLEX mathematical model translating into code

Tags: constraints, cplex, minimization

I am new with CPLEX and I am translating a mathematical model to code. Some outputs are wrong and I don't know why. The question that may I ask you, is if the following constraint iscorrectly translated into code.

[Constraint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Ajvs.png)

```
range t=1..2;
range v=1..4;
range vl=0..4;
range vll=1..5;
dvar boolean x[vl][vll][t];
      
forall (i in v, k in t)
 constraint:     
sum(j in vll: j!=i) x[i][j][k] == sum (j in vl: j!=i) x[j][i][k];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
range t=1..2;
range v=1..4;
range vl=0..4;
range vll=1..5;
dvar boolean x[vl][vll][t];

subject to
{
      
forall (i in v, k in t)
 constraint1:     
sum(j in vll: j!=i) x[i][j][k] == sum (j in vl: j!=i) x[j][i][k];

}
```

works fine

Similar thread at https://community.ibm.com/community/user/datascience/communities/community-home/digestviewer/viewthread?GroupId=5557&MessageKey=aa3e9ac6-5003-46af-93b0-dce6c83cc9b6&CommunityKey=ab7de0fd-6f43-47a9-8261-33578a231bb7&tab=digestviewer&ReturnUrl=%2fcommunity%2fuser%2fdatascience%2fcommunities%2fcommunity-home%2fdigestviewer%3fcommunitykey%3dab7de0fd-6f43-47a9-8261-33578a231bb7%26tab%3ddigestviewer&SuccessMsg=Thank%20you%20for%20submitting%20your%20message.#bmaa3e9ac6-5003-46af-93b0-dce6c83cc9b6